# iOS 9 NSUserActivity eligibleForSearch / Spotlight Search index/ handoff Device limitation

Tags: ios9, corespotlight

I've implemented correctly NSUserActivity.eligibleForSearch on an iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 9, and am getting Spotlight Search results from my private index.

However, when I attempt to do this same thing with a 3rd generation iPad 3 (iPad3,3)

Does anyone know of a known list of supported devices for private index / handoff for Spotlight Search in iOS 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the list of hardware support:

> **Which devices are these APIs supported on?**
>
> App Search comes with iOS9, available as a free software update for iPhone 4s and later, iPod touch (5th generation), iPad 2 and later, iPad mini and later. However, the search functionality of NSUserActivity and CoreSpotlight are not supported on the iPhone 4s, iPad 2, iPad (3rd generation), iPad mini, and iPod touch (5th generation).

From here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/tn2416/_index.html